# Renaming a Mac OS X App

Tags: rename, macos, .app

I want to rename the app I'm working on. I have changed the Bundle Name to the new name and I've also renamed the whole Xcode project. But for some reason the the .app file has the original name. Is there something I'm missing?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: I think to remember having to change something in the build target's info too. Easiest is to just create a new project and copy everything into it. Maybe this link is usefull http://arustisha.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/on-the-renaming-of-xcode-projects/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the Product Name under Packaging in Build Settings for the target?

By default it is set to the target name, but you can set it to what you want.

You may need to manually edit various items in the menus in MainMenu.xib, too.

Comment: Thanks! It turned out that the Product Name was still the old name.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning and rebuilding the project. But also make sure the CFBundleDisplayName isn't set to the old name in Info.plist. You might also try searching your build settings for the name just to make sure.